# How to hide DatePicker after changed date in DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf

### here is my code. please helps me

in the normal state should not be displayed datepicker and after editing should appear

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date of receiving">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateReceipt}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: wrong tag... please edit

Comment: A tag for this question is definitely wrong

Comment: you should change tag to `C#`

Comment: ups sorry, i'm newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a text-only cell template and a separate editor template:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date of receiving">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateReceipt}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateReceipt,StringFormat=d}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: If it solved your problem, you should accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)